# Meteor Unable to update package catalog. Proxy issue?

Tags: macos, meteor

I am behind a Huge and Mean Company Firewall. Ports are all closed except 8080 and 1080 on which HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS are getting through.

Curl works with `export https_proxy:proxy_port`.

Meteor `meteor add package` fails with

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

 => Errors while parsing arguments:

While adding package accounts-passwords:
error: no such package

Your package catalog may be out of date.
Please connect to the internet and try again.
```

How-to fix?

Comment: I have the exact problem on my OSX machine, but the machine is NOT behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to use meteor behind a corporate firewall.

From https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

Examples:

on Linux or Mac OS X export

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 export
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 meteor update
```

on Windows

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 SET
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678 meteor update
```

Comment: what about socks proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because the package you're looking for is called "accounts-password", not "accounts-password**s**". Hence "error: no such package".